# Is there an easy way to change filetype association?

Tags: unity, default-programs

After the upgrade to 11.10 I've had the problems that

- all music-files would open with banshee, which then crashed
- all folders would open with konsole

The first problem I  after installation of "ubuntu tweak" "> admin > filetype Associations".. Changed back to totem.

The second was somehow not accessible this way (did not give any possibility to add commands).

I've changed the line "inode/directory=nautilus-folder-hanlder.desktop" to "inode/directory=nautilus.desktop" from "/usr/share/applications/defaults.list" and now everything works fine.

Question: More convenient ways to do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can install '[Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)' which has an option to easily change filetype associations. Pay attention that you install the version corresponding to your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 3):

I use `sudo sed -i 's/oldapp.desktop/newapp.desktop/g' /usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list` to switch quickly from an app for all types of associated files to another

Answer (score 1):

I normally press properties on the desire file and on the "open-with" tab I select the application I want to use to open it
The problem is, if you want to change all of them, the only way I found easy, is to use gedit and replace the application name with the desire one on the .desktop file you named before