# Is there any application for editing the file type associations?

Tags: default-programs, file-association

Somehow, on my computer at work the default application for JPG files is ... wine !
Wine is not even installed anymore.

I can "open with" other applications. 
But no matter what i've tried "wine" still remains the default.

I want to completely delete the "wine" from the list of applications that can open JPG.

Is there any application that would allow me full access (see, edit, delete) to all the file associations for ALL the file types ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71904/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-filetype-association ;)

Answer (score 1):

**To change the default program to open images**

- Open System Settings by typing it in the dash.
- Go to "Details" in the bottom row.
- Click "Default Applications"
- The last option is called 'Photos'. I suggest using Image Viewer (it should be this by default)

**To remove wine program associations according to [Wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-0889dfe8795340015e07cb12e8f26f701012d534)**

- Open Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)
- Paste these commands in, one after the other:

  ```
  rm -f ~/.local/share/mime/packages/x-wine*
  rm -f ~/.local/share/applications/wine-extension*
  rm -f ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/*/*/application-x-wine-extension*
  rm -f ~/.local/share/mime/application/x-wine-extension*
  ```