# File type associations gone wild

Tags: google-chrome, file-format

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 (Desktop, 64Bit) on different machines. However, after installing the most recent version of Google Chrome browser and wine I do always get a mess with a lot of file type associations:

- Folders and Archives -> Chrome Browser (results in again downloading them from disk)
- textfiles, TeX, ... -> Wine notepad
- png, jpg, ... -> Wine Internet Explorer
- pdf -> GIMP
- maybe some more

Meanwhile other file type associations stay correct:

- odt, odp, ... -> LibreOffice
- eps -> Document Viewer
- most others

Is there a simple trick to tell Ubuntu to go back to default file type associations without searching for everything which fails and correcting it by hand?

Note: I haven't observe this behavior on the 32Bit version.

Comment: This might be a bug. I am also affected by it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71904/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-filetype-association ->Ubuntu Tweak

Comment: Is there a  possibility to do this automatically without having to look which file type associations fail in detail ?